Keyboard - why is key[36]=down
I am new to linux and I use Lubuntu.
My Pc is Dell 15 3542.
I have a Laptop with Chickony Built-in Keyboard.
I have some issues with the keyboard and I have found out that:
xinput --query-state 13 | grep down
    key[36]=down

Sometimes the output is :: key[104]=down
Why is that?
I don't Press any key at all.
enter code here
xinput --list

⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Synaptics s3203                           id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                         id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell WMI hotkeys                          id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    

Thank you very much :)

Keycode 36 is the Return/Enter key (see xmodmap -pke). I guess you pressed the enter key to start the xinput command, and that showed that the enter key was indeed down. I must say that I can't reproduce this though.

Thank you :]
You were correct.
keycode  36 = Return NoSymbol Return
keycode 104 = KP_Enter NoSymbol KP_Enter
